# How to displays all members of the object as a string like in Immediate Windows?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I noticed that many objects in the Immediate Window window can be parsed to strings to see various members of them, which is quite convenient, but this is not possible with the `toString()` method, because its conversion effect is too poor to show anything.

.NET seems to provide such a mechanism, but I haven't found any information about it on the web.

How can I generate such strings in my own code using the mechanism?

PowerShell also has such a mechanism. It seems that it is widely used.

```
# Tostring Method

d_0_str
"."
h_0_str
"System.Collections.Hashtable"
```

```
# Immediate Windows Native

d_0
{.}
    Attributes: Directory
    CreationTime: {4/21/2022 8:42:11 AM}
    CreationTimeUtc: {4/21/2022 12:42:11 AM}
    Directory: {D:\\MyDocs\\bin\\Debug}
    …………
    IsReadOnly: false
    LastAccessTime: {5/11/2022 12:13:36 PM}
    ……
    Length: 'd_0.Length' threw an exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'
    LinkTarget: null
    Name: "."
    OriginalPath: "."
    
h_0
Count = 3
    ["Two"]: 2
    ["One"]: 1
    ["Three"]: 3
```

```
public class ExploreAndDiffObjectTests
{
    static public Hashtable h_0 = new Hashtable()
    {
        {"One", 1},
        {"Two", 2},
        {"Three", 3}
    };

    static public readonly FileInfo d_0 = new FileInfo(".");
    [Test]
    public void ToStringTest()
    {
        var h_0_str = h_0.ToString();
        var d_0_str = d_0.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(h_0_str);
        Console.WriteLine(d_0_str);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use Reflection to get information about object during runtime.

Comment: @PawełŁukasik I know that it can be realized through reflection, but many details need to be considered. I want to find a mature solution instead of designing functions for each object.They already exist in this world.

Comment: Could not use F12 to go directly to the definition? I haven't used any of the functions above, so I don't quite understand what exactly you want. c# has it's own set.

Comment: `toString()` is a virtual method and can be override. Just write your own version to output all the data you need and in the format you like